# How To Get App Version Number From User?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, app-store

I want to log the app version number so when user sends feedback, it will be in the email.

How can I get the number?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
NSDictionary* infoDict = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
NSString* versionNum = [infoDict objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
NSString *appName = [infoDict objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",appName,versionNum];
```

You can send both the appname and version number using this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]]
```